# What effect does brandy have on blood pressure?

Tags: health, spirits

I've heard that Brandy can have an impact on blood pressure, but mixed responses of lower or higher feelings in the human body. What exactly does it do? Does the direction of the effects change over time? What about with different amounts of brandy, with different types, or with repeated use over time? What is the science behind it all?

Answer (score -1):

Brandy affects blood pressure in the same way that any alcohol affects blood pressure. In the short term, alcohol can temporarily increase blood pressure. In the long term, with too much repeated consumption, there can be long-term more permanent blood pressure increases.